# Symfony 2 - Twig templates - Entity function results

Tags: symfony, twig

I am looking for best solution how to send value returned by one of entity function's in `symfony2` to twig template.

The problem is connecting with getting file url for file uploaded according to "How to Handle File Uploads with Doctrine" manual (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html). I was following the last example ("Using the id as the Filename").

In controller I am getting one of `documents` entity.

```
$document = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Documents')->find($id);
```

and I provide entity details to twig template:

```
return $this->render('AppBundle:Documents:details.html.twig', array('document' => $document));
```

However in the template I need to get link to the file which is generated by `getAbsolutePath()` function.

```
 public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->link
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->link;
    }
```

I may use in controller the following code:

```
return $this->render('AppBundle:Documents:details.html.twig', array('document' => $document, 'link' => $document->getAbsolutePath()));
```

but this solution does not seems to tidy for me, as I am already sending `$document` to twig. What would be your practical solution?

Comment: Where did you define `getAbsolutePath()` method to? Your `Document` entity?

Comment: You can access all methods/attributes of an `object` (and arrays) in twig as well. Just do `{{ document.getAbsolutePath() }}` in your template

Comment: The solution would depend on the answer to @Artamiel question! Meanwhile look into this example, if it helps cos the most people prefer to create custom Twig extensions if the logic is more related to templates. [Creating a custom twig extension which accepts parameters](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/opu4/creating-a-custom-twig-extension-which-accepts-parameters)

Comment: There is no need to extend twig for this... As you clearly see out of op's code that `getAbsolutePath` is a public getter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple. In a Twig template you can simply do:

```
{{ document.getAbsolutePath() }}
```

Comment: or even `{{ document.absolutePath }}`